# how find Error on Cordova-plugin-smtp-client Meteor Mobile App

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

Hello im using the cordova plugin cordova-plugin-smtp-client, my code is set as follow:

```
var mailSettings = {
    emailFrom: "",
    emailTo: "",
    smtp: "",
    smtpUserName: "",
    smtpPassword: "",
    port: 25,
    subject: “subject here”,
    textBody: “body here”,
    attachmentsInBase64Format: [],
};

        var success = function(message) {
          window.plugins.spinnerDialog.hide();
          alert("Orden Enviada Satisfactoriamente");
        }

        var failure = function(message) {
          window.plugins.spinnerDialog.hide();
          console.log(message);
        }

        smtpClient.sendMail(mailSettings, success, failure);
```

but my problem is im getting always the error (INVALID ACTION), if any one can help we how to get the real error so i can fix the problem

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you running the app on an Android 6 (or higher) device?

Comment: @AM Yes I am also getting the same issue when trying to run on android 7.1. Is this something related to permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I figured out that the problem was when trying to send multiple email addressed in the emailTo field. If you send to a single email id it would successfully send the email.
In SMTPClient.java you need to change line no 41 to below:

`String[] toArr = json.getString("emailTo").split(",");`

This will fix multiple email address issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's related to permissions, in devices with **Android 6** (or **higher**).

I solved using the [Cordova Diagnostic Plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin), putting in the *onDeviceReady* function the following code:

```
checkPermission = function () {
        setMyPermission = function () {
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestExternalStorageAuthorization(function (status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
                        break;
                    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
                        break;
                    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
                        break;
                    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE:
                        break;
                }
            }, function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
        };
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getPermissionAuthorizationStatus(function (status) {
            switch (status) {
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.GRANTED:
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
                    setMyPermission();
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.DENIED:
                    setMyPermission();
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
                    setMyPermission();
                    break;
            }
        }, function (error) {alert(error); }, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    };

    checkPermission();
```